# Java object browser in eclipse

Tags: java, allocation

I'm almost sure there is tool in eclipse that will allow me to browse my application objects. There is something done for Android called allocation tracked, is there anything similar that I could use in basic Java project?

I'd like to see list of objects that has been created.

What I need is list of all object in my app something like this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/track-mem.html

I'd like to see how much memory is allocated to each object.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about at what time you want to see the objects created, and what you want to see about them? I don't know that android tool you refer to ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you're looking for is a profiler. Here is an article on using one bundled with eclipse TPTP:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TPTP-Profiling-Tool/tptpProfilingArticle.html

There are some articles on the web that describe different profilers:

http://slashdot.org/story/06/06/30/0053237/Java-Profilers---Which-One-Are-You-Using

The one I'm using and are very happy with is JProfiler. It's not free though.

Answer (score 0):

when you run your application do it in debug mode.  This allows you to set break points where the state of the application essentially freezes and you can brows the run-time stack and see the values currently associated with an Object or field.

Comment: I edited question, I need a list of objects, this is not easy to get what I need.

Comment: sorry there are a lot of them out there, is it for a specific type of application?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a profiler, you can dowload [tptp](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/) for profiling..